# Prevent window.onload being overridden

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to overcome event handlers being overridden?
I have a script say a.js

```
window.onload = function () {
   //Handler in a.js
}
```

Another script say b.js

```
window.onload = function () {
   //Handler in b.js
}
```

where,

a.js is a kind of 3rd party library built by me

b.js is a publisher who uses my script [I can't do any changes out here]

Will onload handler in b.js override a.js's handler?

If yes, How to prevent this from happening?

Will building a queue of all event handlers in a.js and deque them on event help?

But will a.js know all event handlers for an event upfront untill b.js is loaded?

Thoughts and references would help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `element.addEventListener` or `window.attachEvent` in down-level IE versions.

**Sample `addEvent` method:**

```
function addEvent(node, type, listener) {
    if (node.addEventListener) {
        node.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
        return true;
    } else if (node.attachEvent) {
        node['e' + type + listener] = listener;
        node[type + listener] = function() {
            node['e' + type + listener](window.event);
        }
        node.attachEvent('on' + type, node[type + listener]);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

---

***Note** - Most, if not all, modern JavaScript libraries like `jQuery` and `MooTools` have their own implementations. I recommend leveraging their API's - as they abstract out different browser implementations and have been thoroughly tested.*

Comment: why do we need node['e'+type+listener]? Won't node.attachEvent('on'+type, listener) work?

Answer (score 26):

you should use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/DOM/element.addEventListener) to have various handlers for the same event

```
window.addEventListener("load", yourfunction, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the second statement will override the first one. Because you are using the traditional registration model only one event handle is allowed for any given event and object. The function assignment are not cumulative.
But you can:

```
  window.onload = function () {handlerinb(); handlerina()}
```