# getting values from a input element php and javascript mixture

Tags: php, javascript, html

hello everyone I am trying to make a script that steps through a list and `appends` a score to each record returned by the query. this code below is what's happening in PHP; a `input` is created where I store the number that's going to be processed in a `string`; below that there is a `span` element that displays the text `score` and another `span` that contains the actual score. Finally there's an `echo` that showcases the values generated which look like: `score_pad0, score_pad1, score_pad2`

```
echo "<input type='hidden' id='fetch_array' value=".$score_board." />";
echo "<span>score: </span><span id='score_pad$score_board'></span><br />";
echo "score_pad$score_board";
```

I want to grab the value from `fetch_array` in javascript. I use the following code for that
`var array_id = document.getElementById('fetch_array');` this however returns null when I run it. What am I doing wrong? I've tried to read it out by adding the .value extension. but it only crashed my javascript code.

the onload event is triggered by the a function

```
function initialize(numbers_rows)
{
for(var i=0; i < numbers_rows; i++)
{   
    var node=document.createElement("span");
    node.id="scoreLabel";
    document.getElementById("score_pad"+array_id).appendChild(node);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to access `document.getElementById('fetch_array')` after DOMLoad? Can you paste the full code of yours?

Comment: @Tamil I did use the onload event once in the body does that matter at all? I'm not a javascript expert yet :)

Comment: Ya there is a possibility that the time your javascript code gets executed your DOM might not be ready. As a trial do <body onload='myFunction()'> and wrap your document.getElementById inside myFunction() and see what happens.

Comment: You cannot have the same id for all the children , may be that is the problem, `node.id='scoreLabel'` and `array_id` not defined it should be i

Comment: @Tamil I've been testing with your advice; and yes that does work; it even enables the use of the .value extension again. so how can I call on multiple functions in a onload event?

Comment: @JeffreyKlinkhamer Have posted my answer you can accept it if it had helped u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that the time your javascript code gets executed your DOM might not be ready. As a trial do `<body onload='myFunction()'>` and wrap your `document.getElementById` inside `myFunction()`

If does work incase you wish to have multiple handlers for onload event you need to use 
`addEventListener` [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) for non IE browsers and `attachEvent` for IE.

If you could use jQuery then wrap your javascript code around

```
$().ready(function () {
 // Your Code Goes here &Will be executed after DOM is ready
});
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568006/prevent-window-onload-being-overridden-javascript) question on SO

Comment: @JeffreyKlinkhamer Have added a useful link on the same issue which I asked when I was a javascript beginner ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var array_id = document.getElementById('fetch_array').value;
```

Comment: "I've tried to read it out by adding the .value extension. but it only crashed my javascript code" Clearly specified in OP

Comment: You should ask the original poster only ;) I jus pointed out that your answer seems to be not helpful

Comment: @NaveenKumar thank you for contributing, in the end the .value extension made it's comeback and for filled his role ;)